# gstreamer appsrc video streaming over the network

Tags: gstreamer, xlib

I'm trying to use gstreamer appsrc to play video stream over the network.

I found good examples here.

[gstreamer appsrc test application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746719/gstreamer-appsrc-test-application)

http://amarghosh.blogspot.kr/2012/01/gstreamer-appsrc-in-action.html

Using examples above I can play a video in X Window using Xlib. When pipeline is set PLAYING state, then somehow "need-data" signal emitted and in the start_feed callback function data read from a video file are injected to the appsrc GstBuffer and play sample video.

I'm trying to get data from the network instead of a file, so I think simple echo server reads a video file exactly the same way above and send data to the client when connection is occurred. The client should get these data and put in the appsrc.

My question is how to put stream data to appsrc pipeline? Does anybody give any suggession or good reference?

Here's the working sample code using above links' examples.

```cpp
// http://amarghosh.blogspot.kr/2012/01/gstreamer-appsrc-in-action.html
// http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs476/Xlib/xlines.c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // sleep()
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappbuffer.h>
#include <gst/interfaces/xoverlay.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE (640*480*3)//(1024)
#define BORDER_WIDTH    2

#define DEBUG   printf

typedef unsigned int  uint32;
typedef unsigned char uint8;

typedef struct {
    GstPipeline *pipeline;
    GstAppSrc *src;
    GstElement *sink;
    GstElement *decoder;
    GstElement *ffmpeg;
    GstElement *videosink;
    GMainLoop *loop;
    guint sourceid;
    FILE *file;
} gst_app_t;

static gst_app_t gst_app;

static Window child_window = 0;
static Window window = 0;

static gboolean read_data(gst_app_t *app)
{
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    guint8 *ptr;
    gint size;
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    ptr = g_malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    g_assert(ptr);

    size = fread(ptr, 1, BUFF_SIZE, app->file);

    if(size == 0){
    ret = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(app->src);
    DEBUG("eos returned %d at %d\n", ret, __LINE__);
    return FALSE;
    }

    buffer = gst_buffer_new();
    GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA(buffer) = ptr;
    GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buffer) = size;
    GST_BUFFER_DATA(buffer) = GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA(buffer);

    ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(app->src, buffer);

    if(ret !=  GST_FLOW_OK){
        DEBUG("push buffer returned %d for %d bytes \n", ret, size);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(size != BUFF_SIZE){
        ret = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(app->src);
        DEBUG("eos returned %d at %d\n", ret, __LINE__);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static void start_feed (GstElement * pipeline, guint size, gst_app_t *app)
{
    if (app->sourceid == 0) {
        DEBUG ("start feeding\n");
        app->sourceid = g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) read_data, app);
    }
}

static void stop_feed (GstElement * pipeline, gst_app_t *app)
{
    if (app->sourceid != 0) {
        DEBUG ("stop feeding\n");
        g_source_remove (app->sourceid);
        app->sourceid = 0;
    }
}

static void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad)
{
    GstCaps *caps;
    GstStructure *str;
    gchar *name;
    GstPad *ffmpegsink;
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;

    DEBUG("pad added\n");

    caps = gst_pad_get_caps(pad);
    str = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);

    g_assert(str);

    name = (gchar*)gst_structure_get_name(str);

    DEBUG("pad name %s\n", name);

    if(g_strrstr(name, "video")){

        ffmpegsink = gst_element_get_pad(gst_app.ffmpeg, "sink");
        g_assert(ffmpegsink);
        ret = gst_pad_link(pad, ffmpegsink);
        DEBUG("pad_link returned %d\n", ret);
        gst_object_unref(ffmpegsink);
    }
    gst_caps_unref(caps);
}

static gboolean bus_callback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer *ptr)
{
    gst_app_t *app = (gst_app_t*)ptr;

    switch(GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message))
    {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT: {
        gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_X_OVERLAY (GST_MESSAGE_SRC(message)), child_window);
        }
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        {
        gchar *debug;
        GError *err;

        gst_message_parse_error(message, &err, &debug);
        DEBUG("Error %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        g_free(debug);
        g_main_loop_quit(app->loop);
        }
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_WARNING:
        {
        gchar *debug;
        GError *err;
        gchar *name;

        gst_message_parse_warning(message, &err, &debug);
        DEBUG("Warning %s\nDebug %s\n", err->message, debug);

        name = GST_MESSAGE_SRC_NAME(message);

        DEBUG("Name of src %s\n", name ? name : "nil");
        g_error_free(err);
        g_free(debug);
        }
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        DEBUG("End of stream\n");
        g_main_loop_quit(app->loop);
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
        break;

    default:
        DEBUG("got message %s\n", \
        gst_message_type_get_name (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)));
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static gboolean terminate_playback (GstElement * loop)
{
    DEBUG ("Terminating playback\n");
    g_main_loop_quit ((GMainLoop *)loop);
    return FALSE;
}

int gstreamer_init(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gst_app_t *app = &gst_app;

    GstBus *bus;
    GstStateChangeReturn state_ret;

    app->file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    g_assert(app->file);

    /* initialization */
    gst_init((int)0, NULL);

    app->loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    /* create elements */
    app->pipeline = (GstPipeline *)gst_pipeline_new("my_pipeline");

    app->src = (GstAppSrc *)gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "myappsrc");
    app->decoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin2", "mydecoder");
    app->ffmpeg = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "myffmpeg");
    app->videosink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "myvideosink");

    if (!app->videosink) {
        DEBUG ("output could not be found - check your install\n");
    }

    g_assert(app->src);
    g_assert(app->decoder);
    g_assert(app->ffmpeg);
    g_assert(app->videosink);

    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(app->pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch(bus, (GstBusFunc)bus_callback, app);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    g_signal_connect(app->decoder, "pad-added",
                G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), app->ffmpeg);

    //gst_app_src_set_emit_signals(app->src, true);
    g_signal_connect(app->src, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(start_feed), app);
    g_signal_connect(app->src, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(stop_feed), app);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (app->pipeline), (GstElement *)app->src,
                app->decoder, app->ffmpeg, app->videosink, NULL);

    /* link everything together */
    if (!gst_element_link((GstElement *)app->src, app->decoder)) {

        DEBUG ("Failed to link one or more elements!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!gst_element_link(app->ffmpeg, app->videosink)){
        DEBUG("failed to link ffmpeg and videosink");
        return -1;
    }

    state_ret = gst_element_set_state((GstElement *)app->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (state_ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {

        DEBUG("Failed to start up pipeline!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    DEBUG("set state returned %d\n", state_ret);

    //g_timeout_add (15000, (GSourceFunc) terminate_playback, app->loop);

    g_main_loop_run(app->loop);

    state_ret = gst_element_set_state((GstElement *)app->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    DEBUG("set state null returned %d\n", state_ret);
    gst_object_unref(app->pipeline);

    return 1;
}

/* 
 * gst-launch filesrc location=test.avi ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
 *
 * 1. dependency library install
 *    $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
 *    $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
 *
 * 2. compile
 *    $ gcc hello.c -o hello -lX11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-app-0.10` -lgstinterfaces-0.10
 *
 * 3. how to run program 
 *    $ ./hello <video_file_name>
 *    $  GST_DEBUG=appsrc:5 ./hello ./hbo_dtc_sd.ts 
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *disp;
    Window root;
    long fgcolor, bgcolor;

    GC gc;
    XGCValues gc_val;
    XEvent event;
    char *msg = "Hello, World!";
    int screen;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (disp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(disp);

    root = RootWindow(disp, screen);
    fgcolor = BlackPixel(disp, screen);
    bgcolor = WhitePixel(disp, screen);

    window = XCreateSimpleWindow(disp, root, 100, 100, 1000, 840, 1,
                    fgcolor, bgcolor);

    child_window = XCreateSimpleWindow(disp, window, 100, 100, 800, 600, 1,
                    fgcolor, bgcolor);

    gc_val.foreground = fgcolor;
    gc_val.background = bgcolor;
    gc = XCreateGC(disp, child_window, GCForeground|GCBackground, &gc_val);

    XSelectInput(disp, child_window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

    g_warning("map xwindow");
    //XMapWindow(disp, window);
    XMapWindow(disp, window);
    XMapWindow(disp, child_window);
    XSync(disp, FALSE);

    //XDrawLine (disp, window, gc, 0, 0, 1000, 800); 
    //XDrawLine (disp, child_window, gc, 0, 0, 800, 600); 

    gstreamer_init(argc, argv);

    XDestroyWindow( disp, window );
    XDestroyWindow( disp, child_window );

    XCloseDisplay( disp );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have at least one other thread (on each end) to handle communication over a socket (like TCP, or UDP if on a local network). This typically has a blocking call to wait for packets. To send data, you can form a gstreamer tee and queue, and then an appsrc to buffer/send data to a socket. To receive, you can pull the data from the socket to a buffer. Keep in mind the OS's socket buffer is relatively small and will drop packets if you don't pull from it fast enough, or push to one too fast. Hence the buffers.

On a `NEED_DATA` signal, you pull from that buffer to the pipeline using `pushBuffer()`. And on an `ENOUGH_DATA` signal, you can just keep buffering or dispose of it, whatever your application needs to do.