# Will two need-data signal configured for one app-src work ? g_signal_connect ()

Tags: callback, signals, gstreamer, glibc

Have got a buffer where both the Audio Elementary stream data and Video Elementary stream data resides.  I am using `appsrc` in `push-mode`. Now I want to use `g_signal_connect()` at two different position to configure the same appsrc for `need-data` signals.

Lets say file1 takes care of Audio stream and file2 takes care of Video stream

file1.c

> g_signal_connect((GstAppSrc *) getAppSrc(),
>   "need-data",G_CALLBACK(cbFunction(1)),NULL);

file2.c

> g_signal_connect((GstAppSrc *) getAppSrc(),
>   "need-data",G_CALLBACK(cbFunction(2)),NULL);

Q1. Is is possible/ sensible ?  I mean won't the callbacks get confused which one of the need-data signal to call when appsrc *needs data* ?

**References:**
1 [basic-tutorial-8 short cutting the pipeline](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+8:+Short-cutting+the+pipeline) on gstreamer.
2 [Amarghosh blog](http://amarghosh.blogspot.in/2012/01/gstreamer-appsrc-in-action.html) on appsrc and his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746719/gstreamer-appsrc-test-application)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, write the tsdemuxer as a gst element.

Long answer, you can connect as many singnal handlers as you want, but they will be all fired together. Your cbFunction will need to have all the logic what to push next.