# OpenCv + Gstreamer from an app, getting initial 30s delay

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, rtp

So my application is exposing an RTP stream using `new VideoWriter(pipeline-definition);`

The pipeline definition is:

```
appsrc is-live=1 do-timestamp=1 format=3 stream-type=0 min-latency=0 max-latency=500000000 ! queue leaky=2 max-size-time=500000000 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9000
```

The problem I'm faced with is 30s delay in the stream when viewing it in VLC. No matter what I do, VLC is always 29-30s behind. It seems that  `appsrc` is causing this as the same pipeline with `videotestsrc` has no delay at all.

Any ideas what should I do to make the `appsrc` release the frames to the stream right away?

Comment: I have not used `VideoWriter`, but in my experience, if appsrc is being fed with frames in real-time, then the problem is elsewhere. I had a similar issue where I needed to set sync=FALSE on my pipleine sink... In you case, debug where the frames are being delayed in the pipeline to find the real cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `VideoWriter` has an internal buffer that caches 30s of footage. In my case I was keeping a singleton in memory and relied on it flushing to the pipeline fast enough. In reality I ended up having to force the `VideoWriter` to flush the data by releasing it.

I don't recommend this as a solution to the problem but in my case it worked as I need this pipeline only when `DEBUG` is defined.